# Rabbitmq RPC(request-reply) using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

i want to implement the request-reply pattern for microservices communication using RabbitMQ. However, the issue is that every internal call creates a new queue, and by default, the queue size in RabbitMQ is 30MB. In your architecture, there are 600 internal calls, so:
600 * 30 MB = 18000 MB = 1.8 GB

Is it a best practice to create that many queues?

so how i can avoid that much queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into using an `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/request-reply.html#direct-reply-to

Comment: my replay queue is fixed(in my case 1 reply queue) but request queue is multiple i already explain in my above question. so i want to minimize request queue for utilize memory. –